# Popover on hover vue headllessui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm trying to implement the popover from headlessui of vue package with hover. I try to use the mouseenter and mouseleave and the other mouse events but nothing change.

Any solution? There is a better solution? i search on internet I cant nothing about this. I search on headlessui github discussions but nothing.

```html
<template>
  <div class="fixed top-16 w-full max-w-sm px-4">
    <Popover v-slot="{ open }" class="relative">
      <PopoverButton
        :class="open ? '' : 'text-opacity-90'"
        class="group inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-orange-700 px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white hover:text-opacity-100 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"
      >
        <span>Solutions</span>
        <ChevronDownIcon
          :class="open ? '' : 'text-opacity-70'"
          class="ml-2 h-5 w-5 text-orange-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out group-hover:text-opacity-80"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
      </PopoverButton>

      <transition
        enter-active-class="transition duration-200 ease-out"
        enter-from-class="translate-y-1 opacity-0"
        enter-to-class="translate-y-0 opacity-100"
        leave-active-class="transition duration-150 ease-in"
        leave-from-class="translate-y-0 opacity-100"
        leave-to-class="translate-y-1 opacity-0"
      >
        <PopoverPanel
          class="absolute left-1/2 z-10 mt-3 w-screen max-w-sm -translate-x-1/2 transform px-4 sm:px-0 lg:max-w-3xl"
        >
          <div
            class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5"
          >
            <div class="relative grid gap-8 bg-white p-7 lg:grid-cols-2">
              <a
                v-for="item in solutions"
                :key="item.name"
                :href="item.href"
                class="-m-3 flex items-center rounded-lg p-2 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-orange-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50"
              >
                <div
                  class="flex h-10 w-10 shrink-0 items-center justify-center text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12"
                >
                  <div v-html="item.icon"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-4">
                  <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                    {{ item.name }}
                  </p>
                  <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                    {{ item.description }}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-gray-50 p-4">
              <a
                href="##"
                class="flow-root rounded-md px-2 py-2 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-orange-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50"
              >
                <span class="flex items-center">
                  <span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                    Documentation
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="block text-sm text-gray-500">
                  Start integrating products and tools
                </span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </PopoverPanel>
      </transition>
    </Popover>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like common request in HeadlessUI community.

Another solution found this solution on Github that worked fine for me.

for vanilla vue 3 with js the original solution link [Github Issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/discussions/425)

Nuxt 3 with typescript maintaining accessibility here's the code ↓

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel } from '@headlessui/vue'

interface Props {
  label: string
  hasHref?: boolean
  href?: string
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()

const popoverHover = ref(false)
const popoverTimeout = ref()

const hoverPopover = (e: any, open: boolean): void => {
  popoverHover.value = true
  if (!open) {
    e.target.parentNode.click()
  }
}

const closePopover = (close: any): void => {
  popoverHover.value = false
  if (popoverTimeout.value) clearTimeout(popoverTimeout.value)
  popoverTimeout.value = setTimeout(() => {
    if (!popoverHover.value) {
      close()
    }
  }, 100)
}
</script>

<template>
  <Popover v-slot="{ open, close }" class="relative">
    <PopoverButton
      :class="[
        open ? 'text-primary' : 'text-gray-900',
        'group inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-white text-base font-medium hover:text-primary focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary focus:ring-offset-2'
      ]"
      @mouseover="(e) => hoverPopover(e, open)"
      @mouseleave="closePopover(close)"
    >
      <span v-if="!hasHref">{{ props.label }}</span>
      <span v-else>
        <NuxtLink :to="href">
          {{ props.label }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </span>
      <IconsChevronDown
        :class="[
          open ? 'rotate-180 transform text-primary' : '',
          ' ml-1 h-5 w-5 text-primary transition-transform group-hover:text-primary'
        ]"
        aria-hidden="true"
      />
    </PopoverButton>

    <transition
      enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-200"
      enter-from-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
      enter-to-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
      leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-150"
      leave-from-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
      leave-to-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
    >
      <PopoverPanel
        class="absolute left-1/2 z-10 mt-3 ml-0 w-auto min-w-[15rem] -translate-x-1/2 transform px-2 sm:px-0"
        @mouseover.prevent="popoverHover = true"
        @mouseleave.prevent="closePopover(close)"
      >
        <div
          class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5"
        >
          <div class="relative grid gap-1 bg-white p-3">
            <slot> put content here </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </PopoverPanel>
    </transition>
  </Popover>
</template>
```

Comment: I favor this answer, because it does not break the accessibility, like mentioned in the link. However, when the mouseover event is triggered by the `ChevronDownIcon` the referenced element is wrong. It might be better to reference the the element directly.

Comment: Hey, I have solved it like this, I had to spend sometime on it thou but it solved the issue when focusing the parent. I am using nuxt3 with typescript. I'll modify the response as here is not letting me

Comment: Hey @WnaJ the code with nuxt solution solves mostly the requirements of a menu that should be opened on hover/click and could have a link in the parent menu element.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the docs:[showing-hiding-popover](https://headlessui.com/vue/popover#showing-hiding-the-popover). 
`open` is an internal state used to determine if the component is shown or hidden. To implement your own functionality, you can remove it and use the `static` prop to always render a component. Then you can mange the visibility with your own state ref and a `v-if/v-show`. The `mouse-action` has to be in the upper scope, so it is not triggered leaving the component, e.g. moving the mouse from button to panel.

Below is a modified example from the API documentation:

```
<template>
  <Popover
    @mouseenter="open = true"
    @mouseleave="open = false"
    @click="open = !open"
  >
    <PopoverButton @click="open = !open">
      Solutions
      <ChevronDownIcon :class="{ 'rotate-180 transform': open }" />
    </PopoverButton>

    <div v-if="open">
      <PopoverPanel static>
        <a href="/insights">Insights</a>
        <a href="/automations">Automations</a>
        <a href="/reports">Reports</a>
      </PopoverPanel>
    </div>
  </Popover>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel } from '@headlessui/vue';
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/20/solid';
const open = ref(false);
</script>
```